# Create new page on the same web server in PHP

Tags: php, html

So, I'm trying to create a blogging website, where everyone can post a blog on the website, and that would create a new webpage. I have searched all over the internet for this, but i can not find it for some reason...

HTML:

```
<form name="bloginput" action="blogpost.php" method="POST" class="bloginputform">
    <input type="text" name="bloginput" placeholder="Type your blog here..." id="bloginput" class="bloginput">
    <div class="popup">
    <input type="button" placeholder="Submit" id="popupbtn" onclick="toggleHideShow()">
    <span class="popuptext hide" id="myPopup">
        <input type="name" name="author" placeholder="Name:" id="nameinput" class="nameinput">
        <br>
        <input type="email" name="authoremail" id="emailinput" placeholder="E-mail..." class="emailinput">
        <br>
        <label class="filelabel" id="filelabel">
            <input type="file" name="post-image" accept="image/*" id="fileinput" class="fileinput">
            <p class="fileinputtext" id="fileinputtext">
                Upload Image:
            </p>
        </label>
        <p><button class="crossbtn" onclick="toggleHideShow()" id="crossbtn">✕</button><input type="submit" value="Post" placeholder="Post" class="submitbtn" id="submitbtn"></p>
    </span>
</form>
```

What I have so far in my PHP file:

```php
<?php
    $blogtext = $_POST["bloginput"];
    $author = $_POST["author"];
    $email = $_POST["authoremail"];
    $image = $_POST["post-image"];
    header("Location: http://blogmedia.nl/make")
?>
```

You can find all of this on http://blogmedia.nl

Comment: Normally you need to save the user's input into say a database record (or at least save in a txt file) and then use such data to display in the "blog" record

Comment: @KenLee well yes, but my problem is creating a new webpage every time a blog is posted.

Comment: then just create the page. (there are PHP commands like fopen, fwrite, etc.)

Comment: Wait thats a thing? thanks haha, i didnt know about that. thanks alot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't create any new page, it just displays data that it have received from the form.

Please, search examples by keywords "Creating simples blog on PHP+MYSQL".
Your code on PHP should include at least a connection to the existing database,
at least one INSERT statement to save new data in the database, and error checks (that data before insertion was valid and database saved data successfully). To display data, you should use SELECT statement to receive latest data or list of all posts in the database.

Examples how to work with the database via mysqli ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php))